# Wordpress LMS plugin

Tags: wordpress

I need to find a wordpress LMS plugin that supports event based courses, meaning that the course will last for a certain duration and has a beginning and end date, more like how a physical course would.

I would like the option that members of a different access level can access all the courses for free, where as other members had to pay for each course.

Another feature that lets admins create a new course by copying the content of an existing course would be ideal too.

Does anyone know of a good, supported wordpress plugin that has these features.

Doesn't need to be free.

Answer (score 1):

There are a quite a few. WooCommerce has a product called "Sensei" which is pretty good at this for a stand-alone WordPress install. It's owned by Automattic now, so support is obviously great.

For a hosted solution, the Rainmaker platform http://rainmakerplatform.com/ is an awesome solution. It costs more per month but they give you a TON of tools for marketing your site too. And they'll save you as much money as you pay them in getting your site up.

I've used both solutions and they are both very good.